# How To check if user has emptied a input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to use the on() function of jquery to see what user is typing.. If user types something i will make my div ".hiddenm" visible (It is initially display: none;). As the user starts typing it gets "inline-block" which is perfect.What I am not liking is when user empty that input area its still visible(inline-block) which should not be. I wrote this code.

I tried this

```js
if($("#mobileNumberEntered").val().length == 0){
    $('.hiddenm').css('display', 'none');
}

$("#mobileNumberEntered").on('change keyup paste' , function(){
    $(".mobNumeric").html($("#mobileNumberEntered").val());
    $('.hiddenm').css('display', 'inline-block');
    $('.mobNumeric').css('color', '#212529');
});
```

This should make it again to display : none but it is not doing anything.

Comment: I think you should put the three last lines into the handler of `on`.  Likewise, you should embrace the event `input` in order to capture every change on that input.

Comment: Your if is only being fired when the parent function (document load most likely?) is happening. Put it inside the .on and it will be checked again every time the input changes.

Comment: put your last three lines inside your event handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your if statement is outside of your function. Take it inside the function and it will work:

```
$("#mobileNumberEntered").on('change keyup paste' , function(){
       if($("#mobileNumberEntered").val().length == 0){
               $('.hiddenm').css('display', 'none');
        }
       else {
         $(".mobNumeric").html($("#mobileNumberEntered").val());
         $('.hiddenm').css('display', 'inline-block');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Glad to be a help :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not an event

```
if($("#mobileNumberEntered").val().length == 0){
               $('.hiddenm').css('display', 'none');
            }
```

What happens when you press Backspace? is a key up and you can get lenght 0
you could try to include it in your on event like this

```
$("#mobileNumberEntered").on('change keyup paste' , function(){
if($("#mobileNumberEntered").val().length <= 0){
      $('.hiddenm').css('display', 'none');
}
else{
      $(".mobNumeric").html($("#mobileNumberEntered").val());
      $('.hiddenm').css('display', 'inline-block');
}
});
```